# How to test the existence of a file from a big array of file name and remove the file name from the array if it doesn't exist in a consistent way?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, file

I am trying to use a meta data array containing filenames in a ML project, problem is some files are not available in my disk storage. My goal is to remove the non existent files from the array by checking if the file is available or not.
I wrote this piece of code in python:

```
for file in meta:
try:
    f = open(data_path + file, 'r')
    f.close()
except: 
    meta.remove(file)
```

The code seems to work but is not consistent, I can run it several times in a row and it would decrease the length of meta every time. ( for eg: Original len(meta) = 65296, after 1 iter len(meta) = 62020, after 2 iter len(meta) = 60653, etc ... )

Is there a reason why my code isn't removing all non existent file in one shot ?
Is there a more consistent way to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from os import path
meta = ['path/to/file1','path/to/file2','path/to/filen']
new_meta = [f for f in meta if path.exists(f)]
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer, it's very similar to the answer from @stilManiac but a little bit more elegant, I'll apply this to my code !

Comment: @Vylly I am happy I manged to help. Feel free to up vote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm following what you want to do, but **never** change a sequence which you use during iterating.
Use something like this:

```py
new_meta = meta
for file in meta:
    try:
        f = open(data_path + file, 'r')
        f.close()
    except:
        # new sequence, not the original one
        new_meta.remove(file)
```

The more consistent way I believe:

```py
from os import path
new_meta = meta
for file in meta:
    if not path.exists(data_path + file):
        new_meta.remove(file)
```

Comment: Thank you for those tips, I really appreciate it, it is indeed more consistent and works fine !